# iOS 6 Wrongly positioned TableViews after redisplaying View

Tags: objective-c, ios6, autolayout

I have a problem with my table views.

There are 3 table views whose horizontal position is changed with an UISegmentControl.
Now, if I open another view above it (via presentViewController) and dismiss it again, the table view position is set back, but everything else is how it was before.

There is no code in the viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear method.

Any ideas how to fix this? Maybe a problem with autolayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uncheck 'Use Autolayout' property of controls in view from File Inspector and adjust the position of controls using Size inspector